# Change order of json-filled array values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm fetching JSON data and putting it into a selectbox. The values in the json array are as follows (in the right order):

```
    (empty) (empty)    
    - (empty)
    0 (empty)
    1 value 1
    2 value 2
    3 value 3
    ...
```

The values in my selectbox on the other hand are as follows:

```
(empty) (empty)
- value 1
1 value 2
2 value 3
3 value 4
...
8 (empty)
0 (empty)
```

So both the order is off, but also the 0 is at the end of the array.

Current code:

```
var obj = [<?= json_encode($this->windings)?>];
var windings_array = [];

for (elem in obj[0]) {
   windings_array.push(obj[elem]);
}

var options = $("#winding").find("option");
$.each(obj[0], function (idx, value) {
    options.eq(idx).attr("data-image", "data:image/png;base64," + value);
});
```

Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Edit: the content of the JSON string:

```
windings =
    {
        "-": "",
        "0": "",
        "1": "value1",
        "2": "value2",
        "3": "value3",
        "4": "value4",
        "5": "value5",
        "6": "value6",
        "7": "value7",
        "8": "value8"
    }
```

Comment: What's the (string) content of `json_encode($this->windings)`?

Comment: I edited my post to show the content of $this->windings.